# Tradeview Chart Transperency Background Fix

Tags: html, debugging, charts

I have an issue with getting the advanced real-time Tradeview chart widget to a transparent background: https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/

This is the code for chart that I've been trying to modify:

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->

<div class="tradingview-widget-container">

<div id="tradingview_f6e17"></div>

<div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL Chart</span></a> by TradingView</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="
https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

new TradingView.widget(

{

"width": 1243,

"height": 800,

"symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",

"interval": "D",

"timezone": "Etc/UTC",

"theme": "light",

"style": "3",

"locale": "en",

"toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",

"enable_publishing": false,

"withdateranges": true,

"hide_side_toolbar": false,

"allow_symbol_change": true,

"watchlist": [

"NASDAQ:MSFT",

"NASDAQ:AMZN"

],

"details": true,

"hotlist": true,

"calendar": true,

"container_id": "tradingview_f6e17"

}

);

</script>

</div>

<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

I've tried to use the `"isTransparent ": true` but without any luck. Does anyone have an idea how this could be fixed?